# WooCommerce Subscription - Change Next Bill Date on New Subscription Depending on Variation ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am on WordPress using WooCommerce and the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin.

I have 1 Product with 3 Subscription Variants:

1. Quarterly (set to renew every 3rd month) Variation ID 208
2. 2 Quarter (set to renew every 6th month) Variation ID 209
3. Annual (set to renew every year) Variation ID 210

I needed a way to force the next bill date depending on which variation a customer purchased.

I'm a 10000% NOOB here. But I was able to piece together the following code. I just want to make sure 2 things:

1. It isn't going to crash my site or bring it down
2. It won't affect renewal orders -- I want this to be on NEW orders only

I really appreciate any help!

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'nextpaymentdatechange', 10, 1);  

function nextpaymentdatechange( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items(); 
foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) {
   $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
   if ( $product_id === 208 ) {
        $subid = $order_id + 1;
        $nextdate = get_post_meta( $subid, '_schedule_next_payment', true );
        $threedays_ago = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '2020-11-1 11:59:59', strtotime( $nextdate )) );
        update_post_meta( $subid , '_schedule_next_payment', $threedays_ago);
   }
    else{ if ( $product_id === 209 ) {
        $subid = $order_id + 1;
        $nextdate = get_post_meta( $subid, '_schedule_next_payment', true );
        $threedays_ago = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '2020-2-1 11:59:59', strtotime( $nextdate )) );
        update_post_meta( $subid , '_schedule_next_payment', $threedays_ago);
    }
         else{
              if ( $product_id === 210 ) {
        $subid = $order_id + 1;
        $nextdate = get_post_meta( $subid, '_schedule_next_payment', true );
        $threedays_ago = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '2021-8-1 11:59:59', strtotime( $nextdate )) );
        update_post_meta( $subid , '_schedule_next_payment', $threedays_ago);
    }
         }
        
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: You might also need to check for NEW order only in your PHP script. something like `if ordersdate >= from todays date` then do `dopaymentchangedate` otherwise do nothing. Have you tested this script by adding into your functions.php ?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I have tested! It's up and running. So far so good! But wasn't sure if it was missing anything. I just dove in!

I did notice this changes the renewal date AFTER the subscription is created. So the "Your next renewal date is.." in the cart, checkout page, and confirmation email all have the original date. I've just removed those from my site for now..